# How to Register beans from all sub packages in Spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am creating new `spring boot` + `jpa` + `thymeleaf` application, I am using many modules which are placed in sub packages. I have structure like `ge.my.project` where is placed my main class with `@SpringBootApplication` and under this `package` I have sub packages `ge.my.project.dao`,`ge.my.project.service`,`ge.my.project.controller` and so on  where are placed my beans.`@SpringBootApplication` scans only beans under base(`ge.my.project`) package but I want to scan `beans` from all sub packages.

I tried many variants to scan `sub packages` :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ge.my.project.controller","ge.my.project.service","ge.my.project.configuration"})
```

and

`@ComponentScan({"ge.my.project.controller","ge.my.project.service","ge.my.proj
ect.configuration"})`

and

`@ComponentScan("ge.my.project.*")`

but nothing works , When I am trying to inject beans using `@Autowired` 
I am getting error like this `Consider defining a bean of type 'ge.my.project.service.ServiceTypeService' in your configuration.`

Here is my main class

```
package ge.my.project;

import ge.ufc.inhouseProjects.controller.ServiceTypeController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


 @SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ge.my.project.controller","ge.my.project.service","ge.my.project.configuration"})
@ComponentScan({"ge.my.project.*"})
@EntityScan({"ge.my.project.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("ge.my.project.dao")
public class InhouseProjectsApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*ApplicationContext applicationContext = */SpringApplication.run(InhouseProjectsApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Here is my full project https://github.com/JavaGeoGroup/inhouseProjects.git

Which is the clearest way to scan all project beans in spring boot application?

Comment: You don't need the `@ComponentScan` or all the other annotations. Only `@SpringBootApplication`, in this case, is enough. It will automatically detect anything in `ge.my.project` as this is where the `InhouseProjectsApplication` is defined and is where Spring Boot starts scanning from. So in short remove all annotations and leave only `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Also looking at your repository you have annotated the interfaces, however you should annotate the implementing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate the implementation and not the interface. So in your case the @Service annotation needs to be set on ServiceTypeDaoImpl-class instead of ServiceTypeDao-interface.

---

You need to annotate your beans (your implementation of interfaces, not spring data repo interfaces) with the **@Component** annotation or one of its sub-annotations like **@Repository, @Service, @Controller, @Configuration**.

From the javadoc of @Component:

```
 * Indicates that an annotated class is a "component".
 * Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection
 * when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.
 *
 * <p>Other class-level annotations may be considered as identifying
 * a component as well, typically a special kind of component:
 * e.g. the {@link Repository @Repository} annotation or AspectJ's
 * {@link org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect @Aspect} annotation.
```

---

*Specific extensions to your code-example:* 
Spring beans start with a small case, so your interface "ServiceTypeDao"will be registred as "serviceTypeDao" as long as you dont set a specific name in the "@Service" annotation.

Comment: I have all this annotations on my beans, `@Service` for classes under `my.project.service` package  `@Controller` for classes under `my.project.controller` classes and so on, I am not missing this annotations, problem is something else.You can take a look on my project, I linked `github`

Comment: You need to annotate the implementation and not the interface. I've downloaded your example, if you annotate your ServiceTypeServiceImpl with @Service you get " Started InhouseProjectsApplication in 4.928 seconds (JVM running for 5.373)".